# XeLaTex/Polyglossia small caps

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, small-caps

When compiled, the following code works  perfectly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\begin{document}
абц АБЦ \textsc{абц} \textit{абц} \textsl{абц}

abc ABC \textsc{abc} \textit{abc} \textsl{abc}
\end{document}
```

However, if I change english to serbian

```
\setdefaultlanguage{serbian}
```

then I get the warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/CMUSerif(2)/m/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/CMUSerif(2)/m/n' instead on input line 8.
```

and small caps do not show correctly. How can I get small caps working in serbian documents (using both Cyrillic and Latin script)?

EDIT: I noticed that if I use

```
\setdefaultlanguage[Script=Latin]{serbian}
```

small caps work correctly, and the problem shows up only if I use

```
\setdefaultlanguage[Script=Cyrillic]{serbian}
```

which is the default option.

Comment: Do small caps make sense in Cyrillic texts?

Comment: Why not? I need to achieve the following effect [Cyrillic Small Caps](http://i.imgur.com/4TaYNnL.png)

Comment: Even the Paratype fonts don't have small caps for Cyrillic

Comment: It seems that CMU Serif font that I use here does support Cyrillic small caps, since everything displays correctly when the language is set to english. [output.pdf](http://i.imgur.com/4DNCXO5.png)

Comment: I suppose it's a problem on the font side, because without `polyglossia` and `fontspec` only, declaring the font with `\setmainfont[Script=Cyrillic,Language=Serbian]{CMU Serif}` shows the same problem with `\textsc`. No problem if `Language` is set to `Russian`.

Comment: `\setmainfont[Script=Cyrillic,Language=Default]{CMU Serif}` gives correct output, `\setmainfont[Script=Cyrillic,Language=Serbian]{CMU Serif}` does not show small caps, while `\setmainfont[Script=Cyrillic,Language=Russian]{CMU Serif}` gives warning `Language 'Russian' not available for font 'CMU Serif' with script 'Cyrillic', 'Default' language used instead.` and works, but only since it goes back to default language.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works. Since the problem is in the Language/Script combination, I temporary switch to the default language for all small caps.

```
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}[SmallCapsFont={CMU Serif},
                        SmallCapsFeatures={Language=Default,Letters=SmallCaps}]
```

If there are any better solutions, please describe them.